# Problems with template argument deduction when extending std::span

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to extend `std::span` to have a bounds checked `operator[]` (I am aware `gsl::span` provides this)

I have declared my container as follows:

```
#include <span>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename ... TopArgs> class BoundsSpan : private std::span<TopArgs...> {
public:
    typename std::span<TopArgs...>::reference operator[](std::size_t idx) const {
        if (idx >= this->size()) [[unlikely]] {
            throw std::out_of_range(std::string("span out of bounds access detected - wanted index [" + std::to_string(idx) + "] but size is " +
                                                std::to_string(this->size())));
        }
        return std::span<TopArgs...>::operator[](idx);
    }
    template<typename ... Args>
    BoundsSpan(Args&& ... args) : std::span<TopArgs...>(std::forward<Args>(args) ...) {}
};
```

This seems to work great, however I noticed that template argument deduction no longer works. E.g.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    BoundsSpan span(argv, argc);
}
```

gives a "Too few template arguments for class template 'span'" and requires an explicit `BoundsSpan<char*>` instead - this is not the case with regular `std::span`

Additionally, constructing a `BoundsSpan` on a C-style array with runtime length gives a "variably modified type cannot be used as a template argument" - did I overlook a template specialization here? An example reproducer would be

```
void func(int len) {
    int arr[len];
    BoundsSpan<int> span(arr, len);
}
```

Comment: (a) How do you expect the compiler to deduce `TopArgs` from `Args`?  (b) *"a C-style array with runtime length"* is not standard C++, but a compiler extension the provides C VLA's. It doesn't have to work in any particular way with templates. It can simply *not* work.

Comment: If you want to extend `std::span`, it is better not to inherit privately.

Comment: (a) good point, I have no idea how to do this. (b) this works with the base class, but not with `BoundsSpan`

Comment: "*however I noticed that template argument deduction no longer works.*". Then write a CTAD yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The std::span template parameter list is not compatible with your variadic parameter list.  It takes:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class span {...};
```

However, your class is working in terms of a variadic type list.  There is no way for you to propagate the template parameters "up" to the span base when it wants a non-type template parameter, and you only pass types.  It's best to try matching the template signature of the span you're impersonating.  That brings some simplifications to the problems:

- you can expose all of the span constructors as your own (i.e. `using std::span<T, N>::span;`)
- You can use the same deduction guides that the std::span has, renamed for your class.

Here's a revised version of your code that I found to be functional:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N = std::dynamic_extent> 
class BoundsSpan : private std::span<T, N> {
public:
    using std::span<T, N>::span;
    using std::span<T, N>::data;
    using std::span<T, N>::size;
    // .. and all the other interface functions

    typename std::span<T, N>::reference operator[](std::size_t idx) const {
        if (idx >= this->size()) [[unlikely]] {
            throw std::out_of_range("span out of bounds - wanted index [" + 
                std::to_string(idx) + "] but size is " + std::to_string(size()));
        }
        return std::span<T, N>::operator[](idx);
    }
};
```

Then taking std::span's deduction guides for inspiration yields:

```
template <class It, class EndOrSize>
BoundsSpan(It, EndOrSize) -> BoundsSpan<std::remove_reference_t<std::iter_reference_t<It>>>;
        
template<class T, std::size_t N>
BoundsSpan(T (&)[N]) -> BoundsSpan<T, N>;
        
template<class T, std::size_t N>
BoundsSpan(std::array<T, N>&) -> BoundsSpan<T, N>;
        
template<class T, std::size_t N>
BoundsSpan(const std::array<T, N>&) -> BoundsSpan<const T, N>;
        
template<class R>
BoundsSpan(R&&) -> 
    BoundsSpan<std::remove_reference_t<std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>>>;
```

With this it should work in your examples and like span.  You might want to also wrap the `const` version of operator[].

https://godbolt.org/z/7ec3PYe7e

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense to me! I tried the proper template signature `<class T, std::size_t N = std::dynamic_extent>` first, but I am very unfamiliar with C++' template rules and thought that with variadic parameters it may be able to automatically deduce the constructors - apparently not. Thanks!

Comment: @Jannik2099 different areas of responsibility even, deduction happens at substitution level - before instantiation and anything in definition holds the place.  If constructor is a template, it's a separate template for which substitution happens on its own.